# How to get the "dataset" name with SQL in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

In PostgreSQL I can get the database name with [this query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/58332/74114):

```
SELECT current_database();
```

Google BigQuery uses the hierarchy:

- Billing Project
- Project
- Dataset
- Table

How can I determine the `dataset` name with SQL?

Comment: In database terminology, "project" is similar to database, and "dataset" is similar to schema. When you query a table, you usually have to specify the dataset as part of the reference, i.e. `dataset.table`. What is the context in which you are hoping to get the name of a dataset?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard ah ok. I see that with the console, but I was using Tableau Desktop to connect to the data, and in that case, there is a dropdown for Billing, Project and Dataset (and Dataset wasn't part of the query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In BigQuery you don't need to `SELECT current_database();` as you can be in any project an query a table in a different project and dataset as long as you have the permissions. The project, dataset and table are determine in the query:

```
SELECT * FROM [PROJECT_NAME:DATASET_NAME.TABLE_NAME]
```

Your question seems more like a Tableau Desktop question.